# Modify ajax response before any bound callbacks get executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

**ISSUE**

I needed a way to modify all ajax responses in an app before all bound callbacks are triggered.

**SOLUTION**

Standard ajax events, both global and local do not provide a good way to modify the response before app bound callback are triggered.

The order by which ajax events get triggered is the one indicated in the [jquery's ajax event docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events) i.e.

- ajaxStart (Global Event)
- beforeSend (Local Event)
- ajaxSend (Global Event)
- success (Local Event)
- ajaxSuccess (Global Event)
- error (Local Event)
- ajaxError (Global Event)
- complete (Local Event)
- ajaxComplete (Global Event)
- ajaxStop (Global Event)

Notice that there is no hook executed after the response gets back from the server but before success/erorr callback are run e.g. a kind of `ajaxReturn` after `ajaxSend` but before `success|error`

The way i hacked this was to use [$.ajaxPrefilter](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/) which is executed before `ajaxStart` and to wrap the already bound success/error callbacks in another function which will allow me to modify the `options` object and thus the returned data.

Below is the utility function that does the wrapping and an example:

```
var alterResponse = function (opts) {
    var callback = function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
        if (options.url.match(opts.urlMatch)) {
            // Cache original callback.
            var originalSuccess = originalOptions.success || options.success;
            originalOptions.success = options.success = function () {
                // Call wrapper that will modify the response object.
                opts.successWrapper.call(null, options, originalOptions, jqXHR, originalSuccess);
            };
        }
    };
    if (opts.dataTypes) {
        $.ajaxPrefilter(opts.dataTypes, callback)
    }
    else {
        $.ajaxPrefilter(callback);
    }
};

alterResponse({
    urlMatch: /myurl/g, // Filter urls you what to tamper with.
    successWrapper: function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR, originalFn) {
        options.data.customVar = 'customValue';
        originalFn(options, originalOptions, jqXHR);
    }
});
```

I have to mention i'm using this for testing purposes so i'm not concerned about performance, memory and overhead.

Answer (score 10):

If you'd like to modify the data coming back from the server before it reaches the event handler, use dataFilter:

```
    jquery.ajaxSetup({
        dataFilter: function (data, type) {
            //modify your data here

            return data;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use any of the global ajax events

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
   alert("An individual AJAX call has completed successfully");
 });
 //or...
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
  alert("ALL current AJAX calls have completed");
});

//or.. 
$(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({
    complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
        // will be raised whenever an AJAX request completes (success or failure)
    },
    success: function(result) {
        // will be raised whenever an AJAX request succeeds
    },
    etc ... you could use any available option
});
```

});

Comment: from my tests, all callbacks bound to global ajax events are executed after the callbacks for a particular request, even if the global callback are bound first:(